# How do I use a button to get back to my first view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using a single view application template in xcode. I created the first view controller, and then added another with a new .m and .h and xib.

I can click a button IBAction, and get to my second view, however the code I am using for the "back" button wont take me back to my first view, everything crashes. I have included my code which seems to follow the tutorial I was using. Additionally I just control clicked my button and dragged the line to my IBAction in the .h to hook in the secondViewController buttons, which is what I did on the first view controller and it seems to work there.

If anyone can help that would be great!

```
    //from my first view controller .h which works
-(IBAction) buttonPressedPayTable: (id) sender; 

//from my first view controller.m which also works and gets me to the second view
-(IBAction) buttonPressedPayTable: (id) sender
{
SecondViewController *payTableView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:payTableView.view];
}


//from my second view controller .h that will not get me back to the first view without crashing

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{

}
-(IBAction) back: (id)sender;

@end

//from my second view controller .m which doesn't seem to work
#import "SecondViewController.h"


@implementation SecondViewController

-(IBAction) back: (id)sender

{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}




@end
```

Comment: As others have said, use UINavigationController. This way, you won't even have to make your own back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using modal views. So instead of addSubView use:

```
[payTableView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[payTableView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:payTableView animated:YES];
```

Then on the seconViewController back method:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can change the ModalTransitionStyle to the few that apple gives you :D

Hope this helps

Comment: WOW! Nice that was simple to implement with my situation and I actually like the transition, makes me look like I know what I'm doing :p  Elegant and worked right away. Thank you mashdup!!! And thanks to everyone for the thoughtful answers made my night to not have to do this alone!!

Comment: No problem, I tend to use modals if you going to display anything fullscreen. However, if you need to pass data back to the first controller, you need to implement delegates

Answer (score 1):

use UINavigation controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation method for switching from one view controller to the other.

[See the apple docs about view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your second `ViewController` as a `subview` of the `view`.
Use a `UINavigationController` to add the new `UIViewController` to the view stack using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:payTableView animated:YES];`
Then you can either use the nav controllers back button, or use your own button with the code `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Alternately, you can use Storyboards and use a simple segue.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense but I think I'm still missing something, because I put that in and now it wont even take me to the second view at all. The program runs but the button on the first view doesn't do anything. Can you see any problems with my code. I pretty new to this so forgive me if it's obvious.                                            SecondViewController *payTableView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:payTableView animated:YES];

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the code high lighted in my comment, that's how sharp I am at the moment :/

Comment: You need to add a UINavigationController to your first view controller. I think this is do r in the App Delegate where you initiate the first view. I use storyboard to do this as its so much easier

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegate here:

in .h of first view declare a member variable :

```
@interface FirstViewControllerClassName: UIViewController
    {
    SecondViewController *payTableView;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) SecondViewController *payTableView;
```

in .m :

@synthesize payTableView;

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressedPayTable: (id) sender
{
if (!payTableView)
     payTableView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
payTableView.delegate = self;
payTableView.isFinishedSelector = @selector(removeView);
    [self.view addSubview:payTableView.view];
}

- (void)removeView
{
   [payTableView.view removeFromSuperview];
   [payTableView release];
   payTableView = nil;
}


//Just declare a member variable delegate in secondviewcontroller like:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
   id delegate;
   SEL isFinishedSelector;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL isFinishedSelector;


-(IBAction) back: (id)sender;

@end

#import "SecondViewController.h"


@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize isFinishedSelector;

-(IBAction) back: (id)sender

{
         if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:isFinishedSelector])
                [self.delegate performSelector:isFinishedSelector];
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0):

[payTableView.view removeFromSuperview];

i think you are removing  the whole view .that is why app is crashing